# Using '{a..b}' wildcard in fstring

Tags: python, f-string

I'm looking to use `xarray.openmfdataset` to open a specific set of files. For example, I'd like to open file.20180101.nc, file.20180102.nc, file20180103.nc with the following code:

```py
xr.open_mfdataset('./file.{20180101..20180103}.nc', combine='by_coords')
```

The beginning and end integers are stored in variables `ts` and `te`, so I'd ideally like to use an fstring like this:

```py
xr.open_mfdataset('./file.\{{ts}..{te}\}.nc', combine='by_coords')
```

Where the '{}' that don't contain a variable are escaped out. However, I get the following error:
`SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed`

A quick search didn't show any solution to this, is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash`-style brace expansion isn't a glob, and isn't supported by `open_mfdataset`. You can pass a list of file names, however.

```
xr.open_mfdataset(
    [f'./file.{x}.nc' for x in range(ts, te)],
    combine='by_coords'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets in f-strings are escaped with more brackets. `{{` is an escaped open-bracket, and `}}` is an escaped close-bracket.

Accordingly, this should work:

```
xr.open_mfdataset(f'./file.{{{ts}..{te}}}.nc', combine='by_coords')
```

Comment: While this answers half of the question (how to include `{}` in an fstring), as mentioned in the accepted answer `open_mfdataset` doesn't support brace expansion at all, and the accepted answer addresses this. Thanks for your input!